# Choose rows from dataframe by index

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Food  Car  Airplane  Slice  Team
A      F     A         F     A
#With 15 more rows
```

What I would like to do is to choose row number 1 and 14.

This code works to get the first row

```
data[rownames(data) == 1,]
```

```
Food  Car  Airplane  Slice  Team
A      F     A         F     A
```

How can I do so the code chooses two rows?
`data[rownames(data) == 1, 14,]` doesn't work.

Comment: Try: `data[c(1, 14),]`.

Answer (score 1):

tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(15), b = rnorm(15))

df %>% 
  slice(1,14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1,14))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want choose rows by index

```
data[1,]
```

If you want choose rows by List of Index values

```
data[c(1,14),]
```

A full explanation can you find here:
https://sparkbyexamples.com/r-programming/select-rows-by-index-in-r/